# Alignment when not dealing with (just) text

Tags: output-formatting, alignment

In designing interfaces for dynamic operation, I am finding that I cannot figure out how to get alignment to work. For example:

```
Row[{Panel[Column[{1, 2, 3}]], 
     Panel[Column[{4, 5}]], 
     Panel[Column[{6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]]}, 
    Alignment -> {Top, Center}]
```

[image]

How do I get the panels to align to the top of the row?

Comment: Use Grid instead of Row.

Comment: Huh. That *does* work. I'm baffled as to why it doesn't work in Row, but you are correct, it works in Grid. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Kuba for the answer in the comments:

```
Grid[{{Panel[Column[{1, 2, 3}]], 
       Panel[Column[{4, 5}]], 
       Panel[Column[{6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]]}}, 
     Alignment -> {Center, Top}]
```

It is baffling why this doesn't work with Row, but @Kuba is correct that it works perfectly with Grid.

[image]